# Circular dependency: why are these classes un-couplable

Tags: oop, cyclic-reference

I have a class, `Thing`, which has a number of variables. I also have a class, `FileHandler`, which records data to log files.

The `FileHandler` is specific to the instantiation of a `Thing` and needs to print several of the instance variables of `Thing`. So, `Thing` is imported into `FileHandler`.

There is another class, `OtherThing`, which also needs a `Filehadler`. Unfortunately, `Thing` imports `OtherThing` for reasons specific to the nature of `Thing` and `OtherThing`. This means that `FileHandler` imports `Thing` and `Thing` imports `OtherThing` which in turn imports `FileHandler`.

I can't seem to pull these apart. I will add more to this post depending on the comments. Is there an obvious reason that I cannot separate my classes here? It seems to be due to the fact that there is common data, that is needed by three classes.

Comment: Is any of this a problem?

Comment: Please show the relevant code for `Thing`, `OtherThing`, and `FileHandler`. The problem may be language-agnostic from a design point of view, but it will be easier to provide suggestions with a concrete example.

Comment: Being able to see (the pertinent parts of) the code might be somewhat useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this wording...

"All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection... Except for the problem of too many layers of indirection." [David Wheeler]

...I would suggest to add an interface. Without knowing the exact code it's hard to decide. Maybe you try to introduce IThing or IFileHandler.

Comment: I fixed this problem by creating a new class that contained the common fields.  Now Thing and OtherThing and Filehandler call this new class instead of calling each other.  I just needed a more appropriate home for the fields.